# How to sum queryset elements in forloop in django template

Tags: python, django

I have a problem inside a django template. Basically, what I'd like to achieve is this kind of table:

[image: Table]

Below each column where there is Absent or present I'd like to sum the duration. The total duration is on the rightmost column but I'd like to have filtered, student per student, each duration. To better explain myself, Student A and Student D, in this example, should have printed 5:00.

I post some code here:

models.py

```
    class Attendance(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        TheoryCourse, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(
        Instructor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Subject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    learning_objectives = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class AttendanceReport(models.Model):
    attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    presence = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    fiscal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    license = models.ForeignKey(
        License, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, default='default.png')
    id_card = models.ForeignKey(
        IDCard, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cap = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py

```
def course_details(request, pk):
    ''' Students' Detail and classroom details '''
    course = TheoryCourse.objects.get(id=pk)
    students = course.student.all()
    syllabus = course.theory_syllabus
    subjects = syllabus.subject_duration.all()

    total_duration = subjects.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('duration'), output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']
    if total_duration != None:
        total_duration = duration(total_duration)

    ''' Attendance Reports part '''

    attendances = Attendance.objects.filter(course_id=course).order_by('-date')
    attendance_reports = AttendanceReport.objects.filter(
        attendance_id__in=attendances)

    attendance_presence = AttendanceReport.objects.filter(
        attendance_id__in=attendances, student_id__in=students, presence='present')

    total_classroom_duration = attendances.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('duration') * 3600000000, output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']

    total_attendance_presence = attendance_presence.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('attendance_id__duration') * 3600000000, output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']

    context = {
        'course': course,
        'students': students,
        'syllabus': syllabus,
        'subjects': subjects,
        'total_duration': total_duration,
        'attendances': attendances,
        'attendance_reports': attendance_reports,
        'total_classroom_duration': total_classroom_duration,
        'total_attendance_presence': total_attendance_presence,
    }
    return render(request, 'theory/course_details.html', context)
```

Basically, what I'd like to understand, is how to have this kind of filter for each student. total_attendance_presence is working fine but for all students. I have no idea how to render in the table for each student.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to understand who is Student A and Student D. Do you want to show the total_attendance_presence per student? Like Student A's total study time is 5 minute and Student D's total study time is 2 minutes etc?

Comment: Yeah sorry I cut the image. Student A is the first one and Student D the fourth one. Basically the result I should have in the table is for each student 7:00 except these two students that "skipped" (which duration was 2 hours) and they should have 5:00 as result.My problem is that it shows the total duration (31:00, which is the sum of ALL the students)